# Way to analyzing projects on github without downloading them?

Tags: java, github

I am looking for a way to analyze GitHub projects. I am especially interested in size of code and lines of code metrics.

Before I decide if I go for a library or reinvent the wheel it would be great to find comparable projects and look at those metrics to decide how much afford it is to well reinvent the wheel.

Often I would like to use a GitHub project but its stale or has mounting bug issues and it has this code I do not understand. So I often ponder about what to do and having an idea what the final required afford will be helps with that decision.

Comment: "*I am looking for a tool*" you are not new SO user, you should know that questions asking for tools are off-topic here. Please rewrite your question to put more emphasis on what you are trying to achieve. You can mention that you are also willing to accept external tools, but don't make your question sound like you are actually expecting recommendations here.

Comment: GitHub has an API and some libraries that use it: https://developer.github.com/libraries/

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry about that. I am using stack overflow as a board replacement to ask questions. I do not care much about the thing stack overflow tries to think about itself. I asked other devs and they have the same attitude. But you are right I understand the rule but I am not used to think about it before I post. Sorry. I rephrased the question it should now comply.

Comment: @Jeffrey How can the API help in getting those metrics?

Comment: I don't know, but just knowing the API exists seems to be more research than you've shown us.

Comment: @Jeffrey You do not want a comment on this one right?

Answer (score 1):

While this would be thrown off by large binary files in the repository, you could try using github's [search criteria](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/) to start. You can filter based on latest push, language, and size among other criteria.

- "`size:>=30000` Matches repositories that are at least 30 MB."
- "`css pushed:<2013-02-01` Matches repositories with the word "css" that were pushed to before February 2013."
- "`rails language:javascript` Matches repositories with the word "rails" that are written in JavaScript."

So something like 
`pushed:<2015-04-01 size:>=50000 language:java`

would give you all java repos that have a commit in the last month all of the codes with a push in the last month, at least 50 MB in size.

Comment: Thanks for the language tip. Did not knew it. The size of the repository is often misleading since a longer documentation is enough and everything is thrown out of balance. I will remember the size option to weed out too large projects when I look for small solutions and implementations. Like when I needed a BTree and found only large projects using BTrees.